# SBT remote debugging works in intellij but not when executing tests

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I execute the following command in the terminal `sbt -jvm-debug 9999` and start a remote debug configuration with default values in Intellij 15.0.4-1. Next I execute the sbt task `run` and breakpoints work as expected. When I execute the `test` task instead debugging wont work anymore despite the fact that the same code gets executed.

Using `play-scala` activator seed with `Play Framework 2.4`. Tests are written in spec2.
Has anyone an idea what I might do wrong?

Here is my code:

Class DebugTest.scala

```
object DebugTest {
  def helloWorld(): Unit ={
    println("Oh my")
  }
}
```

Class ApplicationSpec.scala

```
import org.specs2.mutable._

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {

  "Application" should {
    "just print oh my in console" in new WithApplication{
      DebugTest.helloWorld()
    }
  }
}
```

File build.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "org.webjars.bower" % "adminlte" % "2.3.3",
  "org.pac4j" % "play-pac4j" % "2.2.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-http" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-cache_2.11" % "2.4.6"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots repository" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

fork in run := true
fork in test := false
```

File test.sbt

```
fork in test := false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play sbt plugin defines the following setting:

```
fork in Test := true
```

So, when you are launching your tests, a different jvm is started (without remote debugging).

You just have to add in your `build.sbt`:

```
fork in Test := false
```

You could even create a `test.sbt` file containing only that line and ignore it from your source control.

This should only be used during debugging. After, please come back to the default behavior; or you can get unexpected results when launching tests multiple times in the same sbt session.

Comment: Updated my question. I tried your suggestion to add an additional test.sbt but still debugging does not work.

Comment: My error was that I wrote `test` instead of `Test`. Everything works now! Thank you so much.